# Firebase roles / API Keys

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm new to Firebase and I'm not sure how to proceed with the following problem:

- Web platform: user signs-in with email & password -> cloud function to create a document in `/users` collection and add a custom claim `admin: true` (read & write)
- How can I generate a **long-lived token** that has a different claim `mobile_client: true`(read-only) that will be used on mobile clients?

I know there is a way to create customTokens using `AdminSDK` but it seems to expire after 1 hour.

Basically I want to achieve something similar when a customer creates an account on web platform.

Using the `Api Key`,  I want to login on the mobile using FirebaseSDK directly.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: All Firebase Auth user ID tokens expire after 1 hour.  There is no way to change that.  What really is the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm planning to create a SDK on top of FirebaseSDK on mobile. On web platform I can create content and on mobile I want only to consume.